# Compile library project with javadocs to jar with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I'm currently trying to, and having a little success, in compiling my library project into a .jar file that also contains javadocs.

When i include `compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'` in my build.gradle file, i end up with exactly what i want for my own library. When i mouseover functions from the library, i see the javadocs they included, and it's a .jar file.

My current code compiles fine, but i end up with an .aar file (despite not having any resources in my library project), and i also don't have javadocs included (They are written in the project though).

My current build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.3.5"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

def groupId = 'com.moonbloom'
def artifactId = 'boast'
def version = '0.3.5'

def localReleaseDest = "${buildDir}/release/${version}"

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = groupId
        pom.artifactId = artifactId
        pom.version = version
        // Add other pom properties here if you want (developer details / licenses)
        repository(url: "file://${localReleaseDest}")
    }
}

task zipRelease(type: Zip) {
    from localReleaseDest
    destinationDir buildDir
    archiveName "release-${version}.zip"
}

task generateRelease << {
    println "Release ${version} can be found at ${localReleaseDest}/"
    println "Release ${version} zipped can be found ${buildDir}/release-${version}.zip"
}

generateRelease.dependsOn(uploadArchives)
generateRelease.dependsOn(zipRelease)

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

And then i simply run 'gradlew clean build generateRelease', and i end up with a .zip file i can upload to JCenter (which works fine).

I found this code here on StackOverflow a while ago, and i can't seem to edit it to work as i want, and i can't seem to find other examples of this working properly.

I don't need automatic upload to Bintray (as i've seen quite a few guides for).

This my current uploaded library:
https://bintray.com/moonbloom/android/Boast/v0.3.5#files

This is Otto, as i want it:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.squareup%3Aotto/1.3.8/view#files

I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're getting an `aar` file because you're using the `android` task. Your javadocs and sources jar files look fine. Either you figured out the problem and forgot to update this question, or I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: How could i edit my build.gradle file to _not_ get a aar file, but a .jar file instead? Because if i remove the android part, it comes up with compile warnings about missing 'compileSdkVersion'.  
The difference between my bintray and Otto's is that their upload is missing some .md5 files, and it's also a .jar file, so they must be using some other way/script to compile their files.

Comment: Using the plugin com.android.library the default packaing is aar. You should  specify the pom packaging 'jar', or you can use a different plugin as java.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti could you give an example of setting the packaging to 'jar' ? Tried to google it, but without any luck

Comment: Sorry but never used jcenter. May be you have to specify pom.packaging = 'jar' in your repositories.mavenDeployer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem, in a kind of hacky way i must admit.

I have my original code (which created the library .aar file and sources/javadocs .jar files)
I found some additional code which could create my library .jar file.
Then i wrote some code myself that moved the library .jar file  to the correct folder and removed some unneeded files.
And i also found some code which could easily turn all the gradle functions into one simple function (which was harder than i had imagined).

This ends up with a perfect .zip file which can easily be uploaded to jcenter, and when i download it by gradle, javadocs work perfectly.

Simply run 'gradlew all', and it'll do everything.

My code is shown below, if anyone has the same issue as me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.4.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
}

def identifier = "com"
def name = "testname"

def groupId = "${identifier}.${name}"
def artifactId = "libraryname"
def version = "0.4.1"

def localReleaseDest = "${buildDir}/release/${version}"
def nearFullPath = "${localReleaseDest}/${identifier}/${name}/${artifactId}"
def fullPath = "${nearFullPath}/${version}"

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = "javadoc"
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = "sources"
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from("build/intermediates/bundles/release/")
    into("${fullPath}/")
    include("classes.jar")
    rename ("classes.jar", "${artifactId}-${version}.jar")

    doLast {
        println "- '${artifactId}-${version}.jar' has been built"
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = groupId
        pom.artifactId = artifactId
        pom.version = version

        repository(url: "file://${localReleaseDest}")
    }
}

task removeUnwantedFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree(dir: "${nearFullPath}/", include: ["*.md5", "*.sha1", "*.aar"])
    delete fileTree(dir: "${fullPath}/", include: ["*.md5", "*.sha1", "*.aar"])

    doLast {
        println "- Unwanted files have been removed in these folders:"
        println "--- ${nearFullPath}"
        println "--- ${fullPath}"
    }
}

task zipRelease(type: Zip) {
    from localReleaseDest
    destinationDir buildDir
    archiveName "${artifactId}-${version}.zip"

    doLast {
        println "- Release ${version} can be found at ${localReleaseDest}/"
        println "- Release ${version} zipped can be found ${buildDir}/release-${version}.zip"
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

def buildAliases = [
        'all' : ['clean', 'build', 'makeJar', 'uploadArchives', 'removeUnwantedFiles', 'zipRelease']
]

def expandedTaskList = []

gradle.startParameter.taskNames.each {
    expandedTaskList << (buildAliases[it] ? buildAliases[it] : it)
}

gradle.startParameter.taskNames = expandedTaskList.flatten()

println "Following tasks have been run: ${gradle.startParameter.taskNames}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line, if you don't want to compile your project as a library:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: But this is actually a library project, and if i change this line, it throws warnings and i can't compile it anymore.

Comment: Ah you're right, nevermind. Why can't you have it as an aar file, if it's for an android project it's pretty much the same thing as everyone can include it?

Comment: As i have 0 resources, and no need for it to be a .aar file, i'd rather it'd be a .jar file (also, so i can learn from my mistakes)

Comment: If it was a generic java project I would say to make it a jar, since it has android gradle projects included I would keep it as a .aar

Comment: Are you sure? the default packaging of the plugin con.android.application is apklib not a jar.